# nodejs: node module for encryption/decryption?

Tags: javascript, node.js, security, encryption

I want a website (A) to only work if the visitor came from a specific other website (B).

Initially, I thought of using `document.referrer`, but apparently it can easily be faked. Guess, I am left with no other option than to pass a key from website A to website B.

Both the websites run on `node` server. I am passing two parameters( say `param1` n `param2`) already, so thought this key, along with some common string shared between two sites( think that is called `private key` )  would make a some sort of encrypted code on site A, add it as third param and send to site B.

In site B, I would de-crypt the third param (using the `private key`) and check if it matches the `param1` and `param2`, then allow passage else return `401`.

I have never done anything like this(security related stuff) before, is this approach correct? Is there any node module that already provides this sort of encryption and decryption? finally, any advice for creating that private key?

Comment: [crypto](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html) is already built in, and offers encryption, hashing etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote an [article](http://www.catalinmunteanu.com/nodejs-aes256-encryption-decryption/) on how to accomplish this using [crypto](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html) nodejs module:

aes_encryption.js:

```
var crypto      = require('crypto'),
    cipher_seed = 'some_random_characters';

var encrypt = function(text) {
    var cipher  = crypto.createCipher('aes-256-cbc', cipher_seed),
        crypted = cipher.update(text, 'utf8', 'hex');

    crypted += cipher.final('hex');

    return crypted;
};

var decrypt = function(text) {
    var decipher  = crypto.createDecipher('aes-256-cbc', cipher_seed),
        decrypted = decipher.update(text, 'hex', 'utf8');

    decrypted += decipher.final('utf8');

    return decrypted;
};

module.exports.encrypt = encrypt;
module.exports.decrypt = decrypt;
```

Usage:

```
var AES = require('path_to_aes_encryption.js');

var data = {
    name:    'Catalin',
    surname: 'Munteanu',
    address: 'Romania'
};

// Encryption
var encrypted_data = AES.encrypt(JSON.stringify(data));

// Decryption
var decrypted_data = JSON.parse(AES.decrypt(encrypted_data));
```

If you plan on doing the encryption on one server and the decryption on other server don't forget to use same `cipher_seed`.